# Deleting files in specific sub-directories created at random

Tags: linux, bash, find, delete-file

I would like to create a script that would delete files older than 5 days from a certain set of subfolders. I'm aware of the following command:

```
find /path/to/files* -mtime +5 -exec rm {} \;
```

The problem that i'm facing at this point, needs some clarification of the structure of my folders:

> /cassandra/data/data/cpms/basket/snapshots
>   /cassandra/data/data/customer/customer/snapshots
>   /cassandra/data/data/profile/customer/snapshots

I want my script to only look in the snapshots folders and clear out files only from there, the problem is that at any point, the application can create a new folder under the 'data' directory, or under a current existing directory. i.e.

> /cassandra/data/data/cpms/**new_basket**/snapshots

OR

> /cassandra/data/data/**new_category**/**new_folder**/snapshots

So to hard code the directories will be irrelevant as soon as the application creates a new structure, it won't work effectively anymore until I update the code.

Is there a way to do a command like this:

```
find /cassandra/data/data <look in *this* directory for a folder named snapshots [it might still be 1 or 2 levels down] in the folders below data> & delete only files older than 5 days in snapshot folders found?
```

So to clarify [I hope], my script should go into the /cassandra/data/data directory, find all the folders named 'snapshots' and delete only files from those folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are in the top level directory where you want to start searching for snapshot folders (note - replaced your '-mtime 5 -exec rm' with just a -ls so you can verify it is finding the folders properly):

```
find . -name snapshot -a -type d | while read a ; do find "$a" -ls ; done
```

or, even easier:

```
find . -path '*/snapshot/*' -a -type f -a -mtime 5 -exec ls -l {} \;
```

Comment: Thank you Wayne. This seems to do exactly what I want. I'm doing some testing now, but so far seems to find what I need. Appreciate the help